# colors inside my component doesn't change using tailwind.config.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

i need to make two themes and i want it to change dynamically based on theme and i am using these two themes "light" and "dark" and this is how i use it inside my component

this is my _app.js

```
export default function App(appProps) 
{
  return (
    <Context>
      <ContextProvider {...appProps}/>
    </Context>
  )
}


function ContextProvider({ Component, pageProps })
{
  const context = useContext(GlobalContext) ;

  const [prefs , setPrefs] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => 
  {
    setPrefs(context?.preferences);
  }, [context])

// here is my issue inside className

  return(
    <div className={`p-3 bg-${prefs?.theme}-primary h-screen`}> // prefs?.theme here is either "dark" or "light"
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and here my tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors:
    {
      "dark":
      {
        "primary":  "#063159",
      },
      "light":
      {
        "primary":  "#grey"
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

when i change  `bg-${prefs?.theme}-primary` to `bg-dark-primary` it work fine but i need it to be dynamically change

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind doesn't work properly with partial dynamic `className`. 
Eg, this won't work:

```html
<div className={`bg-${prefs?.theme}`}>
</div>
```

Tailwind will not actually generate the expected CSS because it is done at build time and the value of `prefs?.theme` can't be known until runtime.

So it needs to be used as a whole:

```html
<div className={`p-3 h-screen ${prefs?.theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-dark-primary' : 'bg-light-primary'}`}>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help i'm new on tailwind and i thought this is gonna work and if you know anything related to this idea from tailwind can you please share it because doing it like this: `${prefs?.theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-dark-primary' : 'bg-light-primary'}`  with big project a little too much

Comment: @NasserAbunasir There isn't anything else you can do other than abstracting it away or using a utility library like `clsx`.
Eg you can create a function in another file that takes `prefs?.theme` and returns the className, or a custom React hook that will return classNames.
`
Here is one implementation using a React hook: `const useDarkClassName = (lightClassName, darkClassName) => {
  const { theme } = useContext(Context)
  return theme === 'dark' ? darkClassName : lightClassName;
};`